# Error: EACCESS: permission denied, open 'build/FILENAME.js'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Docker container fails to start.
Got following error message

I previously tried to set the `build` on 777 but it changes nothing.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/main.js",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir build",
    ...
```

**logs**

```
$ babel src --out-dir build
dispatcher_1   | { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'build/CalcUtil.js'
dispatcher_1   |     at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
dispatcher_1   |     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1190:35)
dispatcher_1   |     at outputFileSync (/app/node_modules/output-file-sync/index.js:115:5)
dispatcher_1   |     at /app/node_modules/@babel/cli/lib/babel/dir.js:117:41
dispatcher_1   |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
dispatcher_1   |     at asyncGeneratorStep (/app/node_modules/@babel/cli/lib/babel/dir.js:74:103)
dispatcher_1   |     at _next (/app/node_modules/@babel/cli/lib/babel/dir.js:76:194)
dispatcher_1   |   errno: -13,
dispatcher_1   |   syscall: 'open',
dispatcher_1   |   code: 'EACCES',
dispatcher_1   |   path: 'build/CalcUtil.js' }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
  db:

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db

  mongoclient:
    image: mongoclient/mongoclient
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb/data
      - MONGOCLIENT_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=mongodb://mongodb/data
    ports:
      - "8071:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  dispatcher:
    image: node:10
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/upload_tmp
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "8070:8070"
    command: "make build start"
    user: "1000:1000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

To start the docker container I use `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Please provide the Dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml or the commands you are using

Comment: @KārlisĀbele I simply use only `docker-compose up -d` to start the docker-container.

Comment: @markovchain the `docker-compose.yml` is above.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: try running

`docker-compose run dispatcher sh` and check whats the owner of the file you are having issues with and if it is the same user as the one you are shelld into

Comment: @KārlisĀbele I am using `Debian GNU/Linux Version 9(stretch)`

Comment: @KārlisĀbele the owner of the folder and the files are `root`

Comment: but in the docker-compose.yml you have user 1000:1000 which is not root

Comment: @KārlisĀbele you are right. I delete this line and it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll make the comment an official answer as well

So in the docker-compose.yml file you have defined that you wish to run the service dispatcher as `user: "1000:1000"` but when you have mounted the volume the owner is actually `root:root`.

I believe that this is a Linux specific issue with permissions when mounting volumes as the owner becomes the user that owns the docker daemon (at least I've encountered this in multiple occasions)

This issue doesn't happen on Docker Desktop for Mac as far as I know and the volumes are mounted with the specified user as owner.

So removing the user definition for that service would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is reporting that the script is trying to open a file and does not have permission to open that file.

Given that the file in question is in the `build` directory as well as the details from the stack trace, I'm guessing that your script is trying to *write* to that file.

The most likely scenario here is that there is no `build` directory in your container and you haven't written any code to create a `build` directory. Since you're using `make` to control your build and you haven't included your `Makefile`, it's hard to know for sure.

Take a look at your build files and make sure that the output directly is explicitly created (if it is missing). You'll also probably want to ensure that its contents are cleared whenever you run a full build.